# React: useReducer Hook trigger twice at first, NOT StrictMode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

**this is *NOT* the problem cause by *StrictMode*.**
here is my code first, a Counter:

```js
let outsideCount = 0
function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useReducer(doCounting, 0)

  function doCounting(count) {
    console.log(`count: ${count}`)
    console.log(`outsideCount: ${outsideCount}`)
    console.log('---------divider---------')

    outsideCount++
    return count + 1
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>count: {count}</span>
      <button onClick={setCount}>Click Me!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

and the output:
click **1** time:

```js
count: 0
outsideCount: 0
---------divider---------
count: 0
outsideCount: 1
---------divider---------  // <<<<<<< That's the point I confused. why it triggered twice?
```

click **2** time:

```js
count: 1
outsideCount: 3            // <<<<<<< I KNEW that cause by StrictMode
---------divider---------  // this time it only trigger once.
// ^^^^^^^^^ but why it trigger twice only at the first click?
```

click **3** time:

```js
click 3 time:
count: 2
outsideCount: 5            // <<<<<<< I KNEW that cause by StrictMode
---------divider---------
// ^^^^^^^^^ the third time trigger once like expected. the first-click confused me.
```

I've already knew that *StrictMode* will make `outsideCount` added twice every click due to test some side-effect that might not be notice by programmer.
and after build as production, the `outsideCount` added once as expected.

but why the first click will trigger function `doCounting` twice?
the `console` shows 2 divider when the first time I click.
also, after build as production,
the `doCounting` ***still*** trigger twice when the first time I clicked.

***Not looking for other solutions or good/bad practice stuff, just wanna know why***

Answer (score 0):

though the behavior or codes' running sequence is not clearly understood yet,
but I think I got some clue about it: `function-memory-address`

the function `doCounting` is triggered and do something at the first time by the click:
---> the `console` printed, the `value` is returned,
then the component *re-rendered*, so the `doCounting` function is re-created *again*.
then, ***somehow***, the re-created function is triggered, ***again***

I guess the second time is the right way what React truly wanna do. *I guess*.

the easiest way to avoid the changing of *function-memory-address* is like the same way we avoid *Object-memory-address* changed: `useMemo` or `useCallback` or `declare-it-outside`

```js
// useMemo
const doCounting = useMemo(() => value => {
  console.log(value)
  console.log('---divider---')
  return value + 1
}, [])

//or

// useCallback
const doCounting = useCallback(value => {
  console.log(value)
  console.log('---divider---')
  return value + 1
}, [])
```

even though I still don't know when the function is triggered, but at least we know that is the memory-address problem.

hope someone to supplement the right codes' running sequence. thx